# How to append classes for dynamic terms in jquery?

Tags: javascript

I have installed a rating module, there I want to change the style. for that what I need is
there is a css class called

```
$('.rate-widget-fivestar)
```

there are totally 3 widgets. the value of five star increses to 1,2,3 for three widgets respectively.

I want to add a class for each widget.
(ie)

```
if($('.rate-widget-1))
 {  //class 1
 }
 if($('.rate-widget-2))
 {  //class 2
 }
 if($('.rate-widget-3))
 {  //class 3
 }
```

how can i acheive that in jquery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below code works for you.

```
if ($('.rate-widget-fivestar').hasClass('rate-widget-1')) {
  $(this).addClass('class1');
}

if ($('.rate-widget-fivestar').hasClass('rate-widget-2')) {
  $(this).addClass('class2');
}

if ($('.rate-widget-fivestar').hasClass('rate-widget-3')) {
  $(this).addClass('class3');
}
```

Comment: `if`'s won't set `$(this)` so it's redundant. Also the `if` statements are redundant. You can just: `$('.rate-widget-3').addClass('class3');` without the if statements.